# Why can't an element defined inside a tr be a child of a tbody?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a little lottery game to learn React. The goal is something like [this](https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/composite/98,05/lottery-ticket-vector-209805.jpg): click a button and it fills a table 18x6 with random numbers.

So I have a `table`, and that table has a `tbody`.

I define a React component, `Ball`, which represents a single table cell containing a number 1-40:

```
const Ball = props => {
    return (
        <td className="ball">
            {Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 1) + 1)}
        </td>
    );
}
```

Then I define a ballRow, which is simply a row of six balls.

```
const ballRow = props => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <Ball />
            <Ball />
            <Ball />
            <Ball />
            <Ball />
            <Ball />
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Now I render my first row in the table:

```
ReactDOM.render(<ballRow />, document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]);
```

But this fails because `<ballrow> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>`.

This confuses me. A `ballrow` is a `tr` element, which is exactly what goes inside a `tbody`. So why wouldn't it be a valid child?

Comment: Maybe: `ReactDOM.render(ballRow, document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ballRow` to `BallRow`.

```
const BallRow = props => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <Ball />
      <Ball />
      <Ball />
      <Ball />
      <Ball />
      <Ball />
    </tr>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<BallRow />, document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]);
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/30484/)

> the JSX tag name convention (lowercase names refer to built-in
>   components, capitalized names refer to custom components).